# PlatformIO will not create firmware.bin in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, firmware, platformio

I downloaded a updated version of some firmware, and need to compile it into a `firmware.bin` file, (`firmware.hex` will not work). Most of the tutorials online said to use PlatformIO for this, but whenever I build the firmware, everything goes as planed, it compiles without any errors and says that it succeeded. However, on most youtube videos or online documents, the last few lines include something like

```
Archiving .pio\build\mega2560\libFrameworkArduino.a
Archiving .pio\build\mega2560\lib9e6\libU8glib-HAL_ID1932.a
Linking .pio\build\mega2560\firmware.elf
Building .pio\build\mega2560\firmware.hex
Checking size .pio\build\mega2560\firmware.elf
Building .pio\build\mega2560\firmware.bin
RAM:   [======    ]  60.6% (used 4963 bytes from 8192 bytes)
Flash: [======    ]  63.7% (used 161682 bytes from 253952 bytes)
================================================ [SUCCESS] Took 222.23 seconds ================================================
```

While mine looks like this:

```
Archiving .pio\build\mega2560\libFrameworkArduino.a
Archiving .pio\build\mega2560\lib9e6\libU8glib-HAL_ID1932.a
Linking .pio\build\mega2560\firmware.elf
Building .pio\build\mega2560\firmware.hex
Checking size .pio\build\mega2560\firmware.elf
RAM:   [======    ]  60.6% (used 4963 bytes from 8192 bytes)
Flash: [======    ]  63.7% (used 161682 bytes from 253952 bytes)
================================================ [SUCCESS] Took 222.23 seconds ================================================
```

And sure enough, there is a `firmware.elf` and `firmware.hex`, but no `firmware.bin`. [Many other places](https://community.platformio.org/t/how-to-make-bin-file-using-platformio-ide/8491/2) say that platformio creates a `.bin` file by default, so I don't think it was something I forgot to do, but then what was it? Do I need to edit my `Platformio.ini` file, or something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same issue when building for an arduino. The solution I found was to add an `extra_script.py` file in the workplace to compile the bin after.

### references

- Details on the post compiling:
  https://docs.platformio.org/en/latest/projectconf/advanced_scripting.html#before-pre-and-after-post-actions
- Details on the script
  https://community.platformio.org/t/add-t-none-or-t-binary/441/14

Basically you want to add the `extra_scripts` line to your `platformio.ini` file

```
; you env might be different to might platform, board and framework be
[env:nanoatmega328]
platform = atmelavr
board = nanoatmega328
framework = arduino

extra_scripts = post:extra_script.py
```

The `extra_script.py` file resides in the same folder as `platformio.ini` and is

```py
from os.path import join
Import("env", "projenv")

# Custom BIN from ELF
env.AddPostAction(
    "$BUILD_DIR/${PROGNAME}.elf",
    env.VerboseAction(" ".join([
                "$OBJCOPY",
                "-O",
                "binary",
                "$TARGET",
                "$BUILD_DIR/${PROGNAME}.bin"
            ]), "Building $TARGET"))
```

Comment: Thanks, I’ll test it when I get back home in about 2 days.

Comment: I'm trying to do this with platformio 5.2.3 (and Marlin firmware) and this is not working for me - I'm just getting as far as `Linking .pio/build/mega2560/firmware.elf` and then a whole bunch of `undefined reference` errors and then `collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status ... [.pio/build/mega2560/firmware.elf]`. Removing the `extra_scripts = ` line makes it all work again. I'm not sure why this is causing the .elf link step to fail? Shouldn't it happen after this step?

Comment: Oddly even having a blank `extra_script.py` causes the same error - it doesn't even get as far as the Post Action.